# Cannot load a youtube video from within a flash movie using google chrome only when embedded in HTML

Tags: html, flash, youtube, actionscript-2

Ok, so this is bizarrely specific and I am not sure how to proceed.

I have a flash movie which loads youtube clips into it.  This works in the following situations:

--> In any browser, it works no matter what, unless it's chrome.

--> In chrome, it loads if you view the swf file directly.

however..

--> If the .swf is embedded via an  tag (of apparently any kind) it will not load the youtube clips.

Fresh from a flash publish:

```
<div id="flashContent">
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="922" height="441" id="map" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="map.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="map.swf" width="922" height="441">
                <param name="movie" value="map.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
```

Here's the two methods I am using to load the thing:

```
//_root.ldr.loadClip(yurl,scrn);
scrn.loadMovie(yurl);
```

and naturally we're:

```
System.security.allowDomain("http://www.youtube.com");
System.security.allowDomain("http://s.ytimg.com");
System.security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.youtube.com/crossdomain.xml");
stop();
```

I am totally at a loss here, because it works fantastically in every other situation, browser, etc...   except this one case.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already using it, make sure you are embeding

`http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/QqXaYoU4piE`

not

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqXaYoU4piE&feature=g-all-u`

also maybe add

`youtube.googleapis.com`

to your security and load the policy file from that domain

Comment: No dice, I added the cross domain from youtube.googleapis.com and load the video..

   `yurl = "http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/"+vid;`

Comment: not sure, i know chrome does some "different" things with flash, but idk, good luck

Comment: Solved:

Problem solved!

For solve wondering and lost in a maddening world of chaos here you go:

Chrome using it's own internal flash player which apparently doesn't like loading external content like all the other flash players.  So...

Download flash player manually from adobe.

Then type in the URL bar:

    `about:plugins`

Hit the + to show details and disable the internal chrome plugin (the location of the file should give it away) and keep the 3rd party flash player active.

Now, when the file loads youtube clips, they will actually load.

Comment: Thats works for you, but what about people visiting your site with chrome? the ones who use stock flash?

Comment: For now, I have placed an alert beneath the video (so it can be viewed if it doesn't load) with a link to instructions on how to fix it.  It's no perfect fix, but I think this is something google/chrome needs to address at this point, so we'll see where I can go taking that route.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the file in the `loadPolicyFile()` call be loaded from the domain where the flash file lives? Otherwise might flash ignore the policy file?

src: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html Within-domain redirects